# Finding an unknown ordinary differential equation

Tags: matlab, ode

Given

```
d²x/dt² + a·dx/dt + 7.9·x³ = 3.2·sin(xt)
```

with initial conditions

```
x(0)     = +1.2
dx/dt(0) = −3.3
x(2.3)   = −0.6
```

Find numerically all the possible values of `a`, each accurate to at least 3 significant digits.

Is there any method other than brute force for solving this?

Comment: Matlab has an [ode solver](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) if you want to solve this practically, or are you asking academically?

Comment: So I meant numerically using Matlab, I know about ode45, but should I take all possible values of a and find x(0) for each and then take the intersection with line y=-0.6. Or, is there any other solution?

Comment: Matlab also seems to have a [symbolic differential equation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/dsolve.html) solver, which should do what you want. About a third of the way down there is an example where they demonstrate solving (for a constant) a second order equation like the one you provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, it is not possible to solve this problem as stated.

Here is what I did. I implemented your problem in a reasonably general way:

```
%{

Find all 'a' for which 

d²x/dt² + a·dx/dt + 7.9·x³ - 3.2·sin(xt) = 0

with initial conditions

x(0)     = +1.2
dx/dt(0) = −3.3
x(2.3)   = −0.6

%}

function odetest

    % See how the function search_a(a) behaves around a = 0:
    test_as = 0 : 0.1 : 10;
    da = zeros(size(test_as));
    for ii = 1:numel(test_as)        
        da(ii) = search_a(test_as(ii)); end

    figure(100), clf, hold on
    plot(test_as, da)
    axis tight
    xlabel('a')
    ylabel('|x(2.3) - 0.6|')


    % Roughly cherry-pick some positive values, improve the estimate, and
    % plot the solutions

    opt = optimset('tolfun',1e-14, 'tolx',1e-12);

    plot_x(fminsearch(@search_a, 0.0, opt), 1)
    plot_x(fminsearch(@search_a, 1.4, opt), 2)
    plot_x(fminsearch(@search_a, 3.2, opt), 3)

    % Plot single solution
    function plot_x(a,N)  

        [xt, t] = solve_ode(a);

        figure(N), clf, hold on
        plot(t,xt)
        plot(2.3, -0.6, 'rx', 'markersize', 20)
        title (['x(t) for a = ' num2str(a)])
        xlabel('t')
        ylabel('x(t)')
    end
end

% Solve the problem for a value a, and return the difference between the
% actual value and desired value (-0.6)
function da = search_a(a)

    a_desired = -0.6;

    xt = solve_ode(a);    
    da = abs(xt(end) - a_desired);
end


% Solve the problem for any given value of a
function [xt, t] = solve_ode(a)   

    y0     = [1.2 -3.3];
    tfinal = 2.3;

    opt    = odeset('AbsTol',1e-12, 'RelTol',1e-6);    
    [t,yt] = ode45(@(y,t) odefun(y,t,a), [0 tfinal], y0, opt);    
    xt     = yt(:,1); % transform back to x(t)  
end

% Most ODE solvers solve first-order systems. This is not a problem for a
% second-order system, because if we make the transformation 
%
%   y(t) = [ x (t)
%            x'(t) ]
%
% Then we can solve for
%
%   y'(t) = [ x' (t)
%             x''(t) ]  <- the second-order homogeneous DE
%
function dydt = odefun(t,y,a)     
    dydt = [y(2)
            -a*y(2) - 7.9*y(1)^3 + 3.2*sin(y(1)*t)];     
end
```

The first part gave me this figure:

[image: solution for all positive a]

Some further investigation suggests that this only grows for larger `a`.

This figure gave rise to the initial estimates `a = [0, 1.4, 3.2]`, which I improved via `fminsearch()` and plotted the solutions of:

[image: x(t) for a ≈ 0.0]
[image: x(t) for a ≈ 1.4]
[image: x(t) for a ≈ 3.2]

So, that probably enables you to hand in your homework :)

However, why I say it's impossible to answer the question as stated, is because this is what the first plot looks like for *negative* `a`:

[image: solution for negative a]

The oscillatory behavior seems to continue indefinitely, and the spacing in between the zeros seems to decrease in a non-predictable way.

Now, my university days are long behind me, and I'm not so well-versed in ODE theory anymore. Perhaps there *is* a pattern to it, that just doesn't show because of numerical problems. Or perhaps the oscillation stops after some value, never to return again. Or perhaps another zero turns up at `a = +1053462664212.25`.

I can't prove any of these things, I just know how to brute-force it; the rest is up to you.

Comment: In the graph it should be `'|x(2.3) + 0.6|'` or `'|x(2.3) - (-0.6)|'`.

Comment: Yeah! I ended up doing the same, and I tested it upto -6, the oscillations continue to happen.This is not a homework though :)